# Disable ok button on JOptionPane.dialog until user gives an input

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need the user to input a name and I want to disable the ok button until some input is given. How can I disable it... ?

Answer (score 27):

`JOptionPane` allows you to supply a component as the message pane and the controls/options that can be displayed on it.

If you add the correct listeners to the message component, then you should be able to influence the controls that are used as options.

Take a look at [JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

**Updated**

For example...

[image]

```
public class TestOptionPane05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane05();
    }

    protected JOptionPane getOptionPane(JComponent parent) {
        JOptionPane pane = null;
        if (!(parent instanceof JOptionPane)) {
            pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)parent.getParent());
        } else {
            pane = (JOptionPane) parent;
        }
        return pane;
    }

    public TestOptionPane05() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JButton okay = new JButton("Ok");
                okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)e.getSource());
                        pane.setValue(okay);
                    }
                });
                okay.setEnabled(false);
                final JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)e.getSource());
                        pane.setValue(cancel);
                    }
                });

                final JTextField field = new JTextField();
                field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                    protected void update() {
                        okay.setEnabled(field.getText().length() > 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update();
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                                null, 
                                field, 
                                "Get", 
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                null, 
                                new Object[]{okay, cancel}, 
                                okay);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am hoping you are still active and can answer my question. Why is it that we need the `getOptionPanel` method? I had tried to set a variable for the `OptionPanel` and call `setValue` inside the `ActionListener` using the variable but it did not work until I implemented your `getOptionPanel` method.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is impossible without overriding `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for **swinglabs** or **jGoodies** libraries for Java. They have built in type for the thing you need.

Answer (score -1):

> I need the user to input a name and I want to disable the ok button until some input is given.

wrong way to do it.

i.e. define 'what is a name' = can be anything.

so, what you're, in effect, trying to do is not accept an empty string,

and you do that as an error-check 'after' the OK button has been pressed.

if empty - pop-up error message/repeat input request/confirm cancel/whatever you want to do

Comment: Well, guess what, sometimes your customer will want exactly what Sanziana describes. So go tell him that's the "wrong way to do it" :)