# JOptionPane Grey Out One Button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need to use a `JOptionPane` to give the user two options. Depending on previous actions though one of the buttons may need to be disabled.

Is it possible with `JOptionPane` to have the ability to set either of the buttons to be disabled or enabled?

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, and it's messy.  Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334931/disable-ok-button-on-joptionpane-dialog-until-user-gives-an-input/14335083#14335083) for an example

Comment: While many things are possible with `JOptionPane` making tweaks and adjustments on it is usually impractical.  In those cases it is better to use a `JDialog`.

Comment: You can use a _JDialog_ customize it like a _JOptionPane_. Its simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you use JButtons:

```
    public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JButton option1 = new JButton("option1");
        final JButton option2 = new JButton("option2");
        option1.setEnabled(false);
        // option2.setEnabled(false);
        option1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                // code here
            }
        });
        option2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // code here
            }
        });
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "hello", "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new JButton[]
        { option1, option2 }, option1);
    }
}
```