# How do i change the default yes_no buttons inside OptionDialog to my own buttons?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I tried to create an array of my custom buttons, and add it as an option in `showOptionDialog` and it's actually worked out but the problem is now they don't behave like a normal yes_no buttons. What should i do to them so they would work exactly like a default one?

Here is my custom button class:

```
public class MenuButton extends JButton {

    MenuButton(String text) {

        super(text);
        setBorder(null);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //setBackground(new Color(153,0,0));

    }

}
```

Buttons:

```
 MenuButton yes = new MenuButton("Yes");
    MenuButton no = new MenuButton("no");
    MenuButton[] yes_no = {yes, no};
```

And method where i am using OptionDialog:

```
void confirmExit() {

        int exitDecision = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Menu.this, "Are you sure?", ":(", 
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, yes_no, yes_no[1]);
        if(exitDecision == 0) { setVisible(false); dispose(); }

    }
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not easily done using `JOptionPane`. The second last parameter in method `showOptionDialog` is meant to be an array of strings. Refer to [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) as well as this SO question: [JOptionPane Passing Custom Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591089/joptionpane-passing-custom-buttons) Perhaps consider creating and using a custom `JDialog` rather than `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Ok, works for me, thank you for your help. I just thought there is a way to easily do it with `JOptionPane`.

Comment: A `JOptionPane` is a great utility class for throwing things (messages, components) on-screen. It is also very configurable and adjustable. But the moment you start thinking *"I'd just like to tweak .."* - it's time to reach for a more generic, simpler class like `JDialog` and just make it the exact way needed.